# What's the name of the font used in the given picture?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I found this image from an unknown source.

[image]

I have searched on  [whatfontis.com](http://whatfontis.com) but could not exact font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [Bank Gothic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_Gothic). Linotype have given it [a page](http://www.linotype.com/5323/theoriginalsquaredsansredrawnbankgothicandmorrissans.html) as well.

[image]